# Result of recent action on admin dashboard may overlap the border

Tags: bug, design, flags, moderator-tools, localization

Result of recent action on admin dashboard may overlap the border:

> [image]

[Original English string](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12217) is slightly shorter:

> Post flag resolved as helpful

As you can see the post long title is processed correctly, there's three dots added to limit the length. But the rest part (result of flag handling) considered as constant length per SE, which isn't true since we have non-English sites.